# Add gradient background to the path element with d3

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I wonder if I could somehow add gradient background to the path element in svg.

I found one solution, but it would be quite 'hard' to implement. I search for a easier, native solution.

So this is the implementation that i found:
1. Add to svg element something like this:

```
<defs>
   <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
   </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

2. Add to the path element such attribute:

```
stroke: url(#grad1);
```

Done.

I would like that the 'easier' solution will apply only css to the path element.
Something like:

```
stroke: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
```

Is there any such ways?

Comment: In a word, no. See e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp or the SVG spec.